# is it possible to add <div> or <span> inside an <option> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i add `<div>` or a `<span>` tag inside an `<option>` tag?

I want the row to be `<option>` of course it has a value and everything, but I need to put a circle red color next to the text in that option, is that possible?

code like:

```
<option value="1">text<div style='background:none repeat scroll 0 0 green;height:25px;width:25px;'></div></option>
<option value="2">text<div style='background:none repeat scroll 0 0 green;height:25px;width:25px;'></div></option>
<option value="3">text<div style='background:none repeat scroll 0 0 green;height:25px;width:25px;'></div></option>
<option value="4">text<div style='background:none repeat scroll 0 0 green;height:25px;width:25px;'></div></option>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## 2019 UPDATE

## This solution doesn't work anymore.

Checked in latest Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

---

It is possible to put a red circle after the text - http://jsfiddle.net/V8cvQ/

```
option:after {
    content: " ";
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    background: #c00;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

...

**UPDATE**

To have different color dots

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option> select </option>
    <option class="red"> one </option>
    <option class="green"> two </option>
    <option class="blue"> three </option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
option:after {
    content: " ";
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

option.red:after { background: #c00; }
option.green:after { background: #0c0; }
option.blue:after { background: #00c; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/V8cvQ/1/)

Comment: wow that's great job man

Comment: @Zoltan how can i add this in the style of the <option> tag ? because i have 3 cases with different colors , Thanks a lot !

Comment: updated to have different colors :)

Comment: i need to add it in the HTML code with `style` if it's possible, how to make the `:after` in the `style=""` ? thanks a lot and sorry for all this troubles :)

Comment: `:after` is a pseudo-element and I think you can't move its' styles into inline CSS of the `<option>` element. You have to use external CSS

Comment: thanks a lot, i don't know but for some reason the `option:after` is not displayed by firebug and it's not working... i added the exact css code :( but select has a `class="select_box"`, maybe that's it ?

Comment: `:after` is a pseudo-element - it's created in CSS, so it won't show up in HTML that Firebug displays

Comment: what could block `:after`? because i added the CSS code in my CSS and it's not working :(

Comment: what browser? http://caniuse.com/#search=after - no support in IE7

Comment: @ZoltanToth Thanks a lot, but your code is not working on chrome or IE>7.0 , you can test on jsfiddle

Comment: take a look - http://stackoverflow.com/q/11903273/1499781

Comment: not working on FF

Comment: not working in 2019

Comment: I suggest you edit the answer and tell users that this solution doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @LGSon good point.

Comment: NOT WORKING IN 2024 -- just vote it down

Answer (score 23):

No.  According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/option), this is what is allowed:

> Permitted content: Text with eventually escaped characters (like `&eacute;`)

Answer (score 8):

Nope, not possible. Or not valid at least.

Answer (score 0):

No. To achieve that you can try this:
Use a div to show the selected item and put a div or a button inside it like a drop-down button. When the button is clicked it shows another div containing all your options.

A little bit complex so not necessary to achieve that effect just to make it look pretty

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using this custom select input

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  a2 = document.createElement("SPAN");
  a2.setAttribute("class", "square-box");
  a2.setAttribute("style", "background-color: " + selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].getAttribute("COLOR"));
  a.appendChild(a2);
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 0; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    d = document.createElement("SPAN");
    d.setAttribute("class", "square-box");
    d.setAttribute("style", "background-color: " + selElmnt.options[j].getAttribute("COLOR"));
    c.appendChild(d);
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var y, i, k, s, h;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerText == this.innerText) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none;
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

.select-items div,
.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.select-items .square-box {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  float: right;
}

.select-selected .square-box {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select>
    <option value="1" color="red">Audi</option>
    <option value="2" color="green" selected>BMW</option>
    <option value="3" color="yellow">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
    <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
    <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
    <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="9">Mini</option>
    <option value="10">Nissan</option>
    <option value="11">Toyota</option>
    <option value="12">Volvo</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can replace your Options with JS plugin:

HTML:

```
<h3>multiSelect = false</h3>
<div id="combo1" class="combo"></div><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="get1">get1</button>&nbsp;
<button id="set1">set1</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
var dd = [];
for(var i=1;i<=4; i++)
    dd.push({ code: i + '', name: 'Employee ' + i });
var cfg = {
    keyField: 'code',
    displayField: 'name',
    multiSelect: false,
    width: 200,
    boxWidth: 200,
    cols : [{
        field: 'code', width: '30%'
    },{
        field: 'name', width: '70%'
    }],
    data: dd
};
var cfg1 = $.extend({}, cfg);
var cb1 = $('#combo1').mac('combo', cfg1);
$('#get1').click(function(){
    alert(cb1.selected);
});
$('#set1').click(function(){
    cb1.select(2);
});
```

});

Don't forget to copy external sources from jsfiddle:
Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/arslantabassum/p5s4jzez/

```
1. copy html
2. copy javascript
3. copy external sources
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok... i added essential parts, and link will not change, because it's my fiddle ... :)