# Displaying HTML Properly in IE <10

Tags: html

The following is working fine in modern browsers and IE 10+. But in IE <10, it's not. In such cases, $staffSelection displays only the first part but not the string concatenated onto it with the option tags. Not sure why...

```
$staffSelection = '<div class="' . $branch . '-' . $staffType . '">';
$staffSelection .= '<option value=""></option>';
echo $staffSelection;
```

Comment: Also, you should add a &nbsp if your going to have an empty element else IE could potentially ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML you have is invalid. Options are only permissible inside of a `select`, `optgroup` or `datalist` element.  The fact that it is showing the way you want in modern browsers should be considered a fluke.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: I actually create the above string and then insert it into <select> tags. The above example is simplified, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: update your question with a better representation of the issue you're having and I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @BenDavidow If that's the case, that's invalid too — you can't put `<div>` elements inside `<select>`.

Comment: If you're trying to have `div`s with / inside of options, this could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890597/is-it-posible-to-add-div-or-span-inside-an-option-tag