# div in <option> tag or alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i found the multipe attribute for the select in the internet. Now i get the idea to use this attribute to make a kind of directory navigation. So if i shift cick on multipe files it will select all between them (like in a normal directory browser). So i tried it out with tow different ways, but i saw that no one work, because of the fact that divs aren't valid in a option element.

The code would be this(it got a bit loger so i post you the jsfiddle link):

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/kg6q9fvm/5/"
```

Is there any possibility to do this?
Hopefully you understand my problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Please also post the relevant code in the question.

Comment: You can't put `div` inside `option`. It's not allowed according to the HTML spec. You can always make your own multi-select widget.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it posible to add <div> or <span> inside an <option> tag ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890597/is-it-posible-to-add-div-or-span-inside-an-option-tag)

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to use `other elements in select options`. you need to use any other plugin which behaves like drop-down like

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: but at the end it shouldn't be a list like in a select element. Instead it should be a row of divs (displayed inline). I just tried to use the select to have the multiselection funktion.