# Angular: ngIf not working for object.property

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm sure I'm in for a :facepalm here, but this seems to have stopped behaving as expected in my upgrade from Angular 7 to 9.

I want to conditionally show a property (`car.type`) if it's not an empty string:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selections.modelId">
  <option *ngFor="let car of selections.possibleCars" [value]="car.modelId" >
    <span *ngIf="car?.type">{{car.type}} - </span>{{ car.modelName }}
  </option>
</select>
```

This used to work to show `car.type` (e.g. "Truck"), but not anymore. If I remove the `*ngIf` clause, I get the value of `car.type`, and it's a non-zero-length string.

The strange thing is that it's showing in the markup, but not on the actual page! In fact, with the below mock data, if I change "DCT111" to "DCT112" then "Batman - " shows up! But strangely, if I change "Batman" to something else, it stays hidden. What's going on?
[image]
Also, if I delete the `<!--bindings` comment, then "Batman" shows up. If I change "Batman" (again, just in Chrome devtools), then it doesn't show up.
I've even hooked up a button on the page to run Change Detection when I click it, and that doesn't make it show up.

Comment: What is the value of `foo.bar`?

Comment: A string, e.g. "Batman"

Comment: How is `*ngIf="foo.bar != null"` behaving?

Comment: It should work in that case. Does the value change at any time in your component?

Comment: seems like something wrong with your bar property

Comment: Could you add code to stackblitz?

Comment: If I do `<span *ngIf="foo.bar">{{foo.bar}}</span>{{foo.bar.length}}` then the length always shows, (or even `bar` if I just did that), but not the one inside the `span`.

Comment: @redOctober13 This might help. MDN says option should contain text only. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: @redOctober13 Could be browser compatiblity issue?

Comment: @redOctober13 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890597/is-it-possible-to-add-div-or-span-inside-an-option-tag/11890623

Comment: @Maihan: oh my word. It was the "span in an option" thing! Maybe a recent version of Chrome broke this? I've been trying to test via CodeSandbox, but everything was showing up fine there, even with a span in an option. I switched it to `<ng-container *ngIf...>` If you want to make this an answer, I'll accept it. And thank you!

Comment: @redOctober13 great to hear. updated my answer. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not solve your problem but might help you. At first the object `foo` is undefined and you are getting data from an API.

Try optional chaining in `*ngIf()`:

```
<span *ngIf="foo?.bar">{{foo.bar}} - </span>{{ foo.otherBar }}
```

Or you can also try:

```
<span *ngIf="foo && foo.bar">{{foo.bar}} - </span>{{ foo.otherBar }}
```

If the `foo` object is `null` then accessing `bar` member would throw an error.

There is no issue with the code you provided. Could be something else causing this.

Give a try detecting changes if it helps:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){}

// After assigning value to the object in the API call.
this.cd.detectChanges()
```

According to MDN, only text is allowed in the option tag. Replace `<span>` with `<ng-container *ngIf...>`.

See more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: Something really strange is going on here. Even if I do `*ngIf="true"` it doesn't show, neither does `*ngIf="false"`. Yet, if I view the HTML in devtools, I can see the markup, but it's not actually showing up on the page! This is so weird...

Comment: I edited original post with an image. It shows up if I change the value in `foo.otherBar` in Devtools. But I had a similar thought as you, and already checked CSS; no issues there.

Comment: it's inside an option tag: `<option *ngFor="let key of selections.fileKeys" [value]="key.loadId" >`

Comment: No, I haven't changed the ChangeDetectionStrategy. I updated the original post with more code.

Comment: Replacing `span` with `ng-container` did the trick. It still feels like a bug in Chrome though that it will show up if I modify something in Devtools, and show up in the markup, just not onscreen.